# Recaptcha and Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, asp.net-web-api, recaptcha

How to display Recaptcha on Windows Phone?

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 and ASP.NET WebApi in backend.

My WebApi method takes some data, recaptcha-challenge and recaptcha-response in parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Method(MyData data, string challenge, string response)
{
    string recaptchaValidationUrl = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify";
    string privateKey = "MY_RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY";

    if (!CheckRecaptcha(recaptchaValidationUrl, request.RcChallenge, request.RcResponse, privateKey,
    HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress))
    {
        return new FindTechResResponse { ErrorMessage = "Invalid captcha code" };
    }
}

public static bool CheckRecaptcha(string recaptchaValidationUrl, string challenge, string response, string privateKey, string clientIp)
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["privatekey"] = privateKey;
        data["remoteip"] = clientIp;
        data["challenge"] = challenge;
        data["response"] = response;

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(recaptchaValidationUrl, "POST", data);
        string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        string isSolvedString = responseString.Split('\n')[0];
        bool isSolved = bool.Parse(isSolvedString);
        return isSolved;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method gets challengeId and loads image

Placeholder `{YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY}` should contain your Recaptcha PublicKey

```
private async Task GetCaptcha()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k={YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY}");
    string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    string captchure = Regex.Match(responseStr, @"challenge\s\:\s\'.+\'").Captures[0].Value;
    string challenge = captchure.Split(':')[1];
    challenge = challenge.Trim('\'', ' ');

    string imageUrl = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c={0}";
    response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format(imageUrl, challenge));
    using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
        CaptchaImage = image;
    }
}
```

In XAML image control binds to `CaptchaImage` property

```
<Image Source="{Binding CaptchaImage}" />
```